# VB.NET - Array of ArrayLists

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, arraylist, vb.net-2010

I've declared an array of 88 arraylists using the following code:

```
Dim Data_FRONT(88) As ArrayList
```

and then I try to add incoming data to it using the following code:

```
Dim Data_In(88) As Double
For i = 0 To 87
    Data_In(i) = 15 ' Hard-coding just to test it
Next

' ...

' Then later in the code after some processing 
For i = 0 To 87
    Data_FRONT(i).Add(Data_In(i))        
Next
```

and I get the following run-time error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I've even tried doing this:

```
For i = 0 to 87
    Data_FRONT(i).Add(15) ' Hard-coding to test it
Next
```

and I still get that error. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually initialize each array list:

```
For i = 0 To 87
    Data_FRONT(i) = new ArrayList() ' Initialize each ArrayList
    Data_FRONT(i).Add(Data_In(i))        
Next
```

That being said, if you are always storing an array of doubles, why not just make a single multi-dimensional array?

```
Dim Data(88,88) As Double = new Double(88, 88)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually collecting data from 88 different sensors, so I want the size of the data structure to increase dynamically.

Comment: @nsax91 You should consider using `List(Of T)` then, instead of ArrayList.

Comment: What's the advantage of using Lists instead of ArrayLists?

Comment: @nsax91 Type safety + speed (no boxing with value types, like double)